# Does deploying a .net web app always have to be so painful when dealing with multiple references to the connection string?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, web-config

Deploying new versions of my web app is taking way too long.  I know there's a better way to do this but I don't know what it is.

Right now I have three projects in a solution, all with their own web.config or app.config, each containing two connection strings.

In each web.config, there's the following:

```
sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="LocalConnection" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Note that it's set to LocalConnection now.  If I publish up to Azure, I have to manually change this to "RemoteConnection".  Every time.

I also have code like this in a few places throughout my app:

```
if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)
            WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("LocalConnection",
                 "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

This means that for each call like this, I have to manually change to "RemoteConnection" when I publish.

Also in my dbContext's empty constructor I call:

```
public AppDbContext()
        : base("name=LocalConnection")
    {

    }
```

Yet another manual update that needs to be done before publishing.  Then all of these have to be reverted manually when I'm back to local testing.

What can I do to make this less tedious?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about [Web.config transformations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx) If you expand Web.config in Visual Studio you will see two more files: Web.Debug.config and Web.Release.config. You can add more configurations, for example Web.Staging.config.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I use a single named connection string and have the transformation define what that is for each sub-config?  How do I tell VS to use Debug or Release?

Comment: This config transforms only come into affect when you publish the project. So for local development box, the standard web.config should contain the dev setting. When you are trying to package the project for deployment on azure, VS runs the config transformation and creates an update config file.

Comment: A similar concept is also available for azure config files. So you can also move your setting into these files. See here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh369934.aspx

Comment: @RobVious Yes you should use a single named connection. You tell VS to use Debug or Release by opening your project's properties and selecting a configuration on the Build tab

Comment: @Chandermani: you should make your comment into an answer - what you suggest is the recommended approach for Azure projects